# SQL 3 tables to join

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

Table `film`

`film_id   title   description   rental_rate`

Table `category`

`category_id   name   last_update`

Table `film_category`

`film_id   category_id   last_update`

I have SQL to select 5 most favorited by rental rate with

```
SELECT title, rental_rate FROM film ORDER BY rental_rate DESC LIMIT 5
```

based of SQL above, how to select 4 most category favorite ?

The result I want is just `category.name`

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What do you mean by "4 most category favorite"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I'm using MySQL

Comment: @Metaphor I mean is the greatest by `rental_rate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
select * from (select t3.name,sum(t1.rental_rate) as rate from film as t1
inner join film_category as t2 on t1.film_id=t2.film_id
inner join category as t3 on t2.category_id=t3.category_id
group by t2.category_id) as detail order by rate DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: many thanks, I change `select t2.name` to `select t3.name` the alias is wrong. thanks.

Comment: sorry for that it will t3.name

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for this:

```
SELECT c.name FROM film a
INNER JOIN film_category b ON a.film_id=b.film_id
INNER JOIN category c ON b.category_id=c.category_id
WHERE a.rental_rate IN 
(
    SELECT TOP (5) rental_rate FROM film    
    ORDER BY rental_rate DESC
)
```

Comment: MySQL does not use the `top` keyword, but `limit`.